# Django Key Error on Form Submit When Overriding Get_Initial on CreateView

Tags: django, forms

I have a generic CreateView that populates a form with some default values along with the primary key value of its parent object. The form is populated correctly, but on submit it throws a KeyError for lumberload_id.

Debugging shows that it overrides the get_initial method on both GET and POST meaning that it tries to access the lumberload object which no longer exists when submitting the form.

It seems to me that there is not a need to get_initial on post back since it has accomplished its job on GET. Is there a way to skip overriding get_initial on POST? I've failed trying to wrapping the override in:

```
if request.method == 'GET':
```

**URL:**

```
 url(r'^lumber_load/(?P<pk>\d+)/addlog/$', views.LogDataCreate.as_view(), name='log-data-add'),
```

**View:**
    class LogDataCreate(CreateView):
        form_class = LogDataForm
        model = LogData

```
    # Set created_by to the current user.
    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.created_by = self.request.user
        return super(LogDataCreate, self).form_valid(form)

    # Set initial values of unit fields.
    def get_initial(self):
        return { 'lumberload': self.kwargs['lumberload_id'],'diameter_unit': '3', 'length_unit': '1' }

    # Return to the load list when done creating a plot.
    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('geoapp:lumber_load_list')
```

**Model:**

```
 class LogData(models.Model):
    logdata_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    lumberload = models.ForeignKey('LumberLoad', blank=True, null=True)
    butt_diameter = models.DecimalField(null=True, max_digits=4, decimal_places=1, blank=True)
    diameter_unit = models.ForeignKey('UnitLengthType', related_name='diameter_unit', null=True)
    log_length = models.DecimalField(null=True, max_digits=3, decimal_places=1, blank=True)
    length_unit = models.ForeignKey('UnitLengthType', related_name='length_unit', null=True)
    speciestreetype = models.ForeignKey('SpeciesTreeType', blank=True, null=True)
    recorded_date = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(User)
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'log_data'
        ordering = ["logdata_id"]
    def __unicode__(self):
        return unicode(self.logdata_id)
```

Comment: **I also tried:**                                                    `def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.lumberLoad = get_object_or_404(LumberLoad, pk=kwargs['lumberload_id'])
        return super(LogDataCreate, self).dispatch(*args, **kwargs)
    
    # Set initial values of unit fields.
    def get_initial(self):
  #      return { 'lumberload': self.kwargs['lumberload_id'],'diameter_unit': '3', 'length_unit': '1' }
        return { 'lumberload': self.lumberLoad.lumberload_id, 'diameter_unit': '3', 'length_unit': '1' }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it this way:

```
def get_initial(self):
    if self.request.method == 'GET':
        return #initial data
    else:
        return {}
```

Comment: Excellent, I had tried wrapping the test for request method around "def get_initial(self)" instead of putting it inside the override. Thanks!!!!!!